# Error related to randomisation test within lapply() function in R

Tags: r, function, lapply, spatstat

I have 30 datasets that are conbined in a data list. I wanted to analyze spatial point pattern by `L function` along with randomisation test. Codes are following. 
The first code works well for a single dataset (data1) but once it is applied to a list of dataset with `lapply()` function as shown in 2nd code, it gives me a very long error like so,

> "Error in Kcross(X, i, j, ...) : No points have mark i = Acoraceae 
>   Error in envelopeEngine(X = X, fun = fun, simul = simrecipe, nsim =
>   nsim,  :   Exceeded maximum number of errors"

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with 2nd code?

```
 grp <- factor(data1$species)               
 window <- ripras(data1$utmX, data1$utmY)      
 pp.grp <- ppp(data1$utmX, data1$utmY, window=window, marks=grp) 
 L.grp  <- alltypes(pp.grp, Lest, correlation = "Ripley")
 LE.grp <- alltypes(pp.grp, Lcross, nsim = 100, envelope = TRUE)  
 plot(L.grp)
 plot(LE.grp)


 L.LE.sp <- lapply(data.list, function(x) { 
   grp <- factor(x$species)               
   window <- ripras(x$utmX, x$utmY)
   pp.grp <- ppp(x$utmX, x$utmY, window = window, marks = grp)  
   L.grp  <- alltypes(pp.grp, Lest, correlation = "Ripley")
   LE.grp <- alltypes(pp.grp, Lcross, envelope = TRUE)  
   result <- list(L.grp=L.grp, LE.grp=LE.grp)
   return(result)
 })
 plot(L.LE.sp$LE.grp[1])
```

Comment: It could be one or more data sets inside your list have data issues affecting your process. Try wrapping in the `function` in [`tryCatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r). If you manually run first code with every data frame, does it work without error?

Comment: yes, it works for every single data frame. Actually I applied another many functions to this data list successfully. But when I add last function (with envelope) to this lappy() function, this error comes out. So I guess there is something wrong with last function of the code

Comment: In first code block you use `q1$utmY` for `ripras` but not in `lapply`.

Comment: sorry actually q1 is data1. in my original code i named q1. here I converted that name into data1 just to be more clear.

Comment: In first code you use the arg `nsim = 100` in second call of `alltypes` but not in `lapply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about the R package `spatstat`.

It would help if you could add a minimal working example including data which demonstrate this problem.

If that is not available, please generate the error on your computer, then type `traceback()` and capture the output and post it here. This will trace the location of the error.

Without this information, my best guess is the following:
The error message says `No points have mark i=Acoraceae`. That means that the code is expecting a point pattern to include points of type `Acoraceae` but found that there were none. This can happen because in `alltypes(... envelope=TRUE)` the code generates random point patterns according to complete spatial randomness. In the simulated patterns, the number of points of type Acoraceae (say) will be random according to a Poisson distribution with a mean equal to the number of points of type Acoraceae in the observed data. If the number of Acoraceae in the actual data is small then there is a reasonable chance that the simulated pattern will contain no Acoraceae at all. This is probably what is causing the error message `No points have mark i=Acoraceae`.

If this interpretation is correct then you should be able to suppress the error by including the argument `fix.marks=TRUE`, that is,

```
alltypes(pp.grp, Lcross, envelope=TRUE, fix.marks=TRUE, nsim=99)
```

I'm not suggesting this is necessarily appropriate for your application, but this should remove the error message if my guess is correct.

In the latest development version of `spatstat`, available on github, the code for `envelope` has been tweaked to detect this error.

Comment: @ Adrian. I wanna make sure what do you mean by "I'm not suggesting this is necessarily appropriate for your application". Should I check CSR by another test? What method do you think appropriate for this? thank you!

Comment: @ Adrian Baddeley. this error message has been solved but another error "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)" appears